# NPM installing package ENOENT Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, npm, npm-install

I have installed npm on my Laravel Project.

When I run `npm install --save vue-draggable`

I get this error

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/victori/Desktop/project-1/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo
```

Although, when I run  `npm install -g --save vue-draggable` it works. Although, id want it onto my actual project files.

NPM Verson: 5.6.0

Node: v8.9.1

Comment: Based on that error, there's a missing folder or file in your `node_modules`. Try deleting the `node_modules` folder, then run `npm install` to reinstall stuff. Then install and save the `vue-draggable` package.

Comment: @Sidney The folder does exist though, I am in it

Comment: Try the reinstall anyway. You could also try restarting your computer, it might be some program has a lock on it (although I think that would be a different error)

Comment: You could also try `npm uninstall vue-draggable` then install again, I will advice you also uninstall it globally

Comment: @HassanSani When I install and un-install globally it works, when im inside my project thats when it fails

Comment: Okay another thing you can try is a new project with a new `npm init` then install it in that project, when creating the new project try to give it a name more like `newproject`

Comment: I cant make a new project when Ive been working on this one